# Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(268215, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required by StandardScaler

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, data-science

I am solving a problem where I am pulling data of all the ProductIDs and then I iterate through the dataframe to look at unique ProductIDs to perform a set of functions.

Here, item is the ProductID/Item number:

```
#looping through the big dataframe to get a dataframe pertaining to the unique ID
for item in df2['Item Nbr'].unique():
        # fetch item data
        df = df2.loc[df2['Item Nbr'] == item]
```

And then I have a set of custom made python functions: 
So, when I get through the first loop (for one productID) it works all great, but when it iterates through the loop and goes to the next Product ID, I am certain that the data it is pulling out is right, but I get this error:

**Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(268215, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required by StandardScaler.**

Although, the X_train and y_train shapes are : (268215, 6) (268215,)

Code Snippet : (Extra Information)

It is a huge file to show. But the initial big dataframe has

[362988 rows x 7 columns] - for first product and 
[268215 rows x 7 columns] - for second product

Expansion of the code:

## the big dataframe with two unique product IDS

biqQueryData = get_item_data(verbose=True)

## iterate over each unique product ID for extracting a subset of dataframes that pertain to the product ID

for item in biqQueryData['Item Nbr'].unique():
    df = biqQueryData.loc[biqQueryData['Item Nbr'] == item]

```
try:
    df_model = model_all_stores(df, item, n_jobs=n_jobs, 
                                    train_model=train_model,
                                    test_model=test_model,
                                    tune_model=tune_model,
                                    export_model=export_model, 
                                    output=export_demand)
```

## the function model_all_stores

```
def model_all_stores(df_raw, item_nbr, n_jobs=1, train_model=False, 
                     test_model=False,  export_model=False, output=False,
                     tune_model=False):
    """Models demand for specified item.

    Predict the demand of specified item for all stores. Does not 
    filter for predict hidden demand (the function get_hidden_demand 
    should be used for this.)

    Output: data frame output
    """

    # ML model hyperparameters 
    impute_with = 'median'
    n_estimators = 100
    min_samples_split = 3 
    min_samples_leaf = 3
    max_depth = None

    # load data and subset traited and valid
    dfnew = subset_traited_valid(df_raw)

    # get known demand
    df_ma = get_demand(dfnew)
    # impute missing sales data
    median_sales = df_ma['Sales Qty'].median()
    df_ma['Sales Qty'] = df_ma['Sales Qty'].fillna(median_sales)

    # add moving average features
    df_ma = df_ma.sort_values('Gregorian Days')
    window_list = [7 * x for x in [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 52]]
    for w in window_list:
        grouped = df_ma.groupby('Store Nbr')['Sales Qty'].shift(1)
        rolling = grouped.rolling(window=w, min_periods=1).mean()
        df_ma['MA' + str(w)] = rolling.reset_index(0, drop=True)

    X_full = df_ma.loc[:, 'MA7':].values
    #print(X_full.shape)
    # use full data if not testing/tuning
    rows_for_model = df_ma['Known Demand'].notnull()
    X = df_ma.loc[rows_for_model, 'MA7':].values
    y = df_ma.loc[rows_for_model, 'Known Demand'].values
    X_train, y_train = X, y 
    print(X_train.shape, y_train.shape)

if train_model:
        # instantiate model components
        imputer = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy=impute_with, axis=0)
        scale = StandardScaler()
        pca = PCA()
        forest = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=n_estimators, 
                                       max_features='sqrt',
                                       min_samples_split=min_samples_split,
                                       min_samples_leaf=min_samples_leaf,
                                       max_depth=max_depth,
                                       criterion='mse',
                                       random_state=42,
                                       warm_start=True,
                                       n_jobs=n_jobs)
        # pipeline for model
        pipeline_steps = [('imputer', imputer),
                          ('scale', scale),     
                          ('pca', pca),
                          ('forest', forest)]
        regr = Pipeline(pipeline_steps)

regr.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

It fails here

**Snippet Of data:**

**biqQueryData** (the entire Dataframe)

364174,1084,2019-12-12,,,,0.0

.....

364174,1084,2019-12-13,,,,0.0

188880,397752,19421,2020-02-04,2.0,1.0,1.0,0.0

.....

188881,397752,19421,2020-02-05,2.0,1.0,1.0,0.0

Subset DF 1:

364174,1084,2019-12-12,,,,0.0
.....

364174,1084,2019-12-13,,,,0.0

Subset DF 2:

188880,397752,19421,2020-02-04,2.0,1.0,1.0,0.0

.....

188881,397752,19421,2020-02-05,2.0,1.0,1.0,0.0

Any help here would be great! Thank you

Comment: Prove to us that "the data it is pulling out is right".  Evidently your code isn't convinced.  You don't give us enough information, either in code or data, to provide much help.

Comment: Hello, I just added the code to the explanation, thank you for that. Please see the code. The data is kind of confidential so unfortunately I cannot share it here. If I get the data per ProductID on two different queries it seems to work well, but when I combine all the results together and then extract subset of the huge dataframe per unique productID is where the problem jumps in. 

Also, when I run the code, the first loop is succesful, the following second iteration fails

Comment: To you and anyone else telling us it is 'confidential' data - just create some analogous dummy data!

Comment: None of us wants to look at a large block of data, confidential or not.  But as long the problem arises with one specific set of data, we can't help you.  You have to identify, for yourself, just what is different about that set.

Comment: @hpaulj I analysed the data. So Ill try to add dummy data here:
Item Nbr,Store Nbr,Gregorian Days,"Inv Qty, BOD",Traited Valid,Valid,Sales Qty
**biqQueryData** (the entire Dataframe)
364174,1084,2019-12-12,,,,0.0
.....
364174,1084,2019-12-13,,,,0.0
188880,397752,19421,2020-02-04,2.0,1.0,1.0,0.0
.....
188881,397752,19421,2020-02-05,2.0,1.0,1.0,0.0

Subset DF 1:
364174,1084,2019-12-12,,,,0.0
.....
364174,1084,2019-12-13,,,,0.0
Subset DF 2:
188880,397752,19421,2020-02-04,2.0,1.0,1.0,0.0
.....
188881,397752,19421,2020-02-05,2.0,1.0,1.0,0.0

I dont see any difference in data

Comment: I added the same point in the question for easier readability